# if first query result is null go to second query in plsql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
procedure sistem_kullanici_ara(ptckno in musteri.tck_no%type,
pcursor  in out sys_refcursor)  is   
 begin      
      open pcursor for
        select *
        from sistem_kullanici sk,
             musteri_rol      mr,
             musteri          m,
             calisan          c,
             rol r,
             departman        d,
             bolge            b
       where sk.calisan_id = c.calisan_id
       and mr.musteri_id = m.musteri_id
       and r.rol_id = mr.rol_id
       and r.rol_id = 2001
       and sk.bolge_kod = b.bolge_kod
       and sk.departman_kod=d.departman_kod
       and sk.bitis_tarih is null
         and m.tck_no = 11111
  end;
```

if this query result is null go to second query

like:

```
open pcursor for
        select *
        from musteri  m

       where m.tck_no = 11111
end;
```

I have two queries and if first query result is null I wan to go to second query.

How can I do this? UNION is not working for me, I need a different method.

Comment: Tip of today: Use the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: yeap i mean null or no records sir

Comment: ahh sorry i forget it. fixed my query in here

Comment: `ptckno` is a parameter and should be passed `m.tck_no = ptckno`, isn't it? Btw, one join condition (most probably among `musteri_rol` and another table) seems missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first you can do count and then proceed with logic:

```
procedure sistem_kullanici_ara(ptckno in musteri.tck_no%type,
pcursor  in out sys_refcursor)  is   

lv_count number := 0;

 begin      
     select count(1) into lv_count
        from sistem_kullanici sk,
             musteri_rol      mr,
             musteri          m,
             calisan          c,
             rol r,
             departman        d,
             bolge            b
       where sk.calisan_id = c.calisan_id
       and mr.musteri_id = m.musteri_id
       and r.rol_id = mr.rol_id
       and r.rol_id = 2001
       and sk.bolge_kod = b.bolge_kod
       and sk.departman_kod=d.departman_kod
       and sk.bitis_tarih is null
         and m.tck_no = 11111;


    if lv_count > 0 then
      open pcursor for
        select *
        from sistem_kullanici sk,
             musteri_rol      mr,
             musteri          m,
             calisan          c,
             rol r,
             departman        d,
             bolge            b
       where sk.calisan_id = c.calisan_id
       and mr.musteri_id = m.musteri_id
       and r.rol_id = mr.rol_id
       and r.rol_id = 2001
       and sk.bolge_kod = b.bolge_kod
       and sk.departman_kod=d.departman_kod
       and sk.bitis_tarih is null
         and m.tck_no = 11111;

     else

      open pcursor for
        select *
        from musteri  m

       where m.tck_no = 11111;
    end if;
  end;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a view :

```
  create view v_sistem_kullanici as 
  select *
    from sistem_kullanici sk
    join musteri_rol      mr on <mr.related_id> = <sk.related_id>
    join musteri          m on mr.musteri_id = m.musteri_id
    join calisan          c on sk.calisan_id = c.calisan_id
    join rol              r on r.rol_id = mr.rol_id
    join departman        d on sk.departman_kod=d.departman_kod
    join bolge            b on sk.bolge_kod = b.bolge_kod
   where sk.bitis_tarih is null
     and r.rol_id = 2001;
```

and then create a procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sistem_kullanici_ara(
                                                 ptckno in musteri.tck_no%type,
                                                 pcursor  in out sys_refcursor
                                                ) IS    
  r_sistem_kullanici  v_sistem_kullanici%rowtype;
BEGIN

  OPEN pcursor FOR 
    select *
      from v_sistem_kullanici
     where tck_no = ptckno;

 FETCH pcursor INTO r_sistem_kullanici; 

 IF pcursor%notfound THEN
     OPEN pcursor FOR 
     select *
       from musteri  m
      where m.tck_no = ptckno;
  END IF;

END;
```

The trick is to consider `c1%notfound` after `fetch..into` statement through the use of local rowtype variable generated by that newly created view.